# Displaying alert from an action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This code works great, but I think it can be reduced.

```
@if (Session["Success"] != null)
{
    <text>
        <div class="alert alert-success">@Session["Success"]</div>
    </text>
    Session.Remove("Success");
}
else if (Session["Error"] != null)
{
    <text>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">@Session["Error"]</div>
    </text>
    Session.Remove("Error");

}
```

Comment: What should happen when `Session` contains both `"Success"` and `"Error"`? Should that behave exactly the same as your code (i.e. print the success case)? Or is that situation impossible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bad idea to modify the session state from inside a view or a partial view. Instead, I would create an alert view model

```
public class AlertViewModel
{
    public AlertType AlertType { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public enum AlertType
{
    None,
    Success,
    Error
}
```

and use that from inside the view/partial view, for example:

```
@if (Model.AlertType != AlertType.None)
{
    string alertClass = Model.AlertType.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();

    <text>
        <div class="alert alert-@alertClass">@Model.Message</div>
    </text>
}
```

This way, you avoid modifying the session where someone else may not expect it, and you have a cleaner view.

About populating the view: I do not know why you are using the session, but if the value is only needed for one request, you should consider using `TempData` instead. In any way, just populate the view model in the controller and remove the session value if you need to.